# Git bash clone not working

Tags: laravel, git-bash

I'm trying to clone a laravel project from github, but it not even responding. Please your help is highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Can you update your post with the command you are attempting to run, along with the results?

Comment: if you at git site there is 2 option for getting repository . 1) get clone by git clone : go at directory where you want clone by git clone url . 2) On GIT site there is download option so you can also download form there . please go with download option .

Comment: Yes it work for me, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to run `git clone https://github.com/someUser/repository.git`. If it still doesn't work for you, try to download GitHub desktop application and login your account then clone the repository. Also you can download the project/repository then do `composer install` and etc.